# Can't change owner of file into a shared drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I want to change the "owner" of a file into a shared drive. However I have no permissions to do that since it says, I can't do that in shared files.

This is the approach I have done so far:

```
param_perm = {}
            param_perm['emailAddress'] = 'john@xxx.nl'
            param_perm['type'] = 'user'
            param_perm['role'] = 'owner'
            service.permissions().create(fileId=file_id,
                                body=param_perm,
                                supportsAllDrives=True,
                                transferOwnership=True).execute()
```

Any other way to accomplish this problem?

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74493905/17926478) answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Ownership transfer is not supported for files and folders within shared drives. As mentioned in this [Drive API Guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-sharing#transfer-organization-account)

> An organization that owns a shared drive owns the files within it. Therefore, ownership transfers are not supported for files and folders in shared drives. Organizers of a shared drive can move items from that shared drive and into their own "My Drive" which transfers the ownership to them.

**Note:** To move files or folders out of a shared drive, you need **Manager** access to the shared drive.

To move a file from a shared drive to "My Drive", you can use the `Files: update` [method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update).

```
service.files().update(
    fileId=file_id,
    addParents=destination_folder_id,
    removeParents=shared_drive_id,
    supportsAllDrives=true).execute()
```

Once you're the owner of the file, you can transfer ownership of the file to another account in the same organization. For this you can use `Permissions: create` [method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create).

```
permission1 = {
        'type': 'user',
        'role': 'owner',
        'emailAddress': 'john@xxx.nl',
}
service.permissions().create(
    fileId=fileId,
    transferOwnership=true,
    body=permission1).execute()
```